# Como soluciono el error StackOverFlow ¿?

Tags: recursión

Tengo el siguiente codigo recursivo que devuelve la matriz con 0"s (espacios en blanco):

```
 public static int[][] llenarMatriz(int f, int c, int i, int j) {

int matriz[][] = new int[f][c];

if (i >= matriz.length) {
    return matriz;
}

matriz[i][j] = 0;
j++;

if (j >= matriz[0].length) {
    i = i + 1;
    j = 0;
}

return llenarMatriz(f, c, j, j);

}
```

Al enviarle las dimenciones me aparece lo siguiente, ¿alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El lugar donde llamo el metodo , intente revisar las condicones del IF cuando entra la matriz pero no es eso, alguna idea?., quizas una Excepsion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando implementes recursividad piensa en los casos que harán que esta termine, si no los hay o son erróneos la función se llamará muchas veces y producirá el error.

Para tu caso la función recursiva podría ser así:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

        int matriz[][] = new int[10][10];

        llenarMatriz(matriz, 0, 0);


    }


    /*
    *
    * La función recibe la matriz a llenar, la fila y la columna
    *
    */
    public static int llenarMatriz(int matriz[][],int f, int c) {

        /*
        * si c  es igual a la longitud de la matriz se reinicia
        * la columna y se incrementa la fila
        *
        */
        if( c == matriz.length ){
            c = 0;
            f++;
        }

        /*
        * si la fila es igual a la longitud de la matriz se retorna 0
        */

        if (f == matriz.length) {return 0;}

        //asignar valor en la posicion [f][c]
        matriz[f][c] = 0;

        //llamada recursiva
        return llenarMatriz(matriz, f, c + 1);

    }
```